# How to publish Unity APK to Play store? Signed in debug mode?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I am very new to Android (Im an apple person) and am trying to build my Unity project for Android to be uploaded to google play store. I've followed all the tutorials and directions from Unity AND google but am having trouble. In desperate need of help.

I've built my project both as an APK and then as a Google Android Project which created a folder on my desktop which i've opened in Android Studio. I've registered as a developer and read up on licensing.

When I try to upload my APK to Google play I get the error my project was signed in debug mode and needs to be in release mode; I've looked at other questions but can't understand how to sign it in release mode. How can I do this exactly?

I don't understand what a Keystore is and saw this under Publish Settings in Unity. Is this related to signing? I have my license key from Google play but this does not work when I enter this as my Keystore.

I do not have an Android device.

How can I upload my APK from Unity to the Google play store?

Comment: stick ONLY with ordinary APK!

Comment: it will be ALMOST IMPOSSIBLE TO DO THIS if you do not own 2 or 3 android devices, sorry for the grim news.  Be aware that it costs **only a hundred bucks** to go to Staples and buy any android tablet.

Comment: Have you read this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/403985/building-for-android.html

Comment: you simply set debug/not mode and you create a keystore, **both on the PublishSettings panel**.  You can very easily google 1000s of pages explaining how to do it.  basically just click "create new keystore".  use THE SIMPLEST POSSIBLE PASSWORD, you can literally >NEVER< forget it or you can't access your items on playstore anymore.

Comment: @JoeBlow where do I set debug/not mode? What mode do I put it in?

Comment: I'm away from my dev machine now, but on the menus there's a "export signed APK", just look for it. The keystore is from the "java keytool" (google it). You create a self-certificate and sign your app with it. VERY IMPORTANT: do never lose the keystore file, do never forget the password. You can only push updates if you sign the app with the same keystore. Here are some Google instructions on it https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html . But all in all I agree with @JoeBlow, u gotta test it in a few real devices.

Comment: The export option is in Android studio or Unity?

Comment: @JoeBlow would you look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800648/building-unity-apk-for-google-play-cant-find-keystore-path?noredirect=1#comment63068075_37800648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is pretty simple, open the MonoDevelop IDE and you would see that your IDE is is Debug mode (Refer the screenshot below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMKn.png)

Change it to Release mode. Try building the app again and upload this new apk to the play store, it should upload all fine this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can build and sign an APK directly from Unity. This link might help:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xsjB4pbnnA

Answer (score 0):

You got to sign the application at android you create something similar to provisioning [profiles by yourself. You need to go Player settings>Publish settings>Create new keystore. Once you have created that you will require a create a key after you did all that make a build now you will be able to upload to google play