# Building Unity APK for Google play- can't find keystore path?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I am trying desperately to export my signed APK after building my Unity project for Android as a "Google development build" and opening it in Android Studio.

I have looked at several other questions and am trying to follow https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html but am having a problem creating my keystore. I have followed the tutorial verbatim but can't create a valid path for the keystone -

I don't understand what I need to do. I have tried `/home/users/keystores/android.jks` I have tried `/home/users/keystores/myprojectname.jks` and just sticking it on my desktop. These are the errors Im getting-

[image]

I have tried locating android.jks but can't find anything using finder. Is it because I am on a mac? What am I doing wrong here? How can I generate my keystore so I can publish?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood, but it appears you haven't yet created a keystore? You have to create your own keystore first and then sign the apk. Check this link  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Comment: No I pressed the "Create new" option like the tutorial said. Your link isn't really helping

Answer (score 0):

`/home/users/keystores/` is most likely not a valid path on your mac. Try to create the keystore in a valid location like in your user's home directory:

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/
```

Verify that the keystore file has been created in that location.

Answer (score 0):

@skyguy You have to create a keystore first using the *`keytool`*.

The keygen tool can be accessed via command line and is already included in the JDK.

If you scroll down that [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) I posted in my comment above, you will see the following example -

> Suppose you want to create a keystore for managing your public/private key pair and certificates from entities you trust.
>
> Generating Your Key Pair The first thing you need to do is create a
>   keystore and generate the key pair. You could use a command such as
>   the following:
>
> ```
> keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=Mark Jones, ou=JavaSoft, o=Sun, c=US"
>   -alias business -keypass kpi135 -keystore /working/mykeystore
>   -storepass ab987c -validity 180 (Please note: This must be typed as a single line. Multiple lines are used in the examples just for legibility purposes.)
> ```
>
> This command creates the keystore named "mykeystore" in the "working"
>   directory (assuming it doesn't already exist), and assigns it the
>   password "ab987c". It generates a public/private key pair for the
>   entity whose "distinguished name" has a common name of "Mark Jones",
>   organizational unit of "JavaSoft", organization of "Sun" and
>   two-letter country code of "US". It uses the default "DSA" key
>   generation algorithm to create the keys, both 1024 bits long.
>
> It creates a self-signed certificate (using the default "SHA1withDSA"
>   signature algorithm) that includes the public key and the
>   distinguished name information. This certificate will be valid for 180
>   days, and is associated with the private key in a keystore entry
>   referred to by the alias "business". The private key is assigned the
>   password "kpi135".
>
> The command could be significantly shorter if option defaults were
>   accepted. As a matter of fact, no options are required; defaults are
>   used for unspecified options that have default values, and you are
>   prompted for any required values. Thus, you could simply have the
>   following:
>
> ```
> keytool -genkeypair
> ```
>
> In this case, a keystore entry with alias "mykey" is created, with a newly-generated key pair and a certificate
>   that is valid for 90 days. This entry is placed in the keystore named
>   ".keystore" in your home directory. (The keystore is created if it
>   doesn't already exist.) You will be prompted for the distinguished
>   name information, the keystore password, and the private key password.
>   The rest of the examples assume you executed the -genkeypair command
>   without options specified, and that you responded to the prompts with
>   values equal to those given in the first -genkeypair command, above (a
>   private key password of "kpi135", etc.)

Once you have created a keystore, you can point to its location and sign your apk.